# how do i construct a sas do loop to get the amount of what's left to be paid?

Tags: sas, finance, retain, do-loops, datastep

hope you can help me.

The below table wants to show the result I want to get by using a sas code.
Basically, it's about calculating the amount of an installment, starting from par_value of 10.000€, with 6% interest rate for 10 years, paying a fixed installment at the end of each period.

| year | fixed_installment | interests | capital_paid | loan_paid | to_be_paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.358,68 € | 600,00 € | 758,68 € | 758,68 € | 9.241,32 € |
| 2 | 1.358,68 € | 554,48 € | 804,20 € | 1.562,88 € | 8.437,12 € |
| 3 | 1.358,68 € | 506,23 € | 852,45 € | 2.415,33 € | 7.584,67 € |
| 4 | 1.358,68 € | 455,08 € | 903,60 € | 3.318,93 € | 6.681,07 € |
| 5 | 1.358,68 € | 400,86 € | 957,82 € | 4.276,75 € | 5.723,25 € |
| 6 | 1.358,68 € | 343,40 € | 1.015,28 € | 5.292,03 € | 4.707,97 € |
| 7 | 1.358,68 € | 282,48 € | 1.076,20 € | 6.368,23 € | 3.631,77 € |
| 8 | 1.358,68 € | 217,91 € | 1.140,77 € | 7.509,01 € | 2.490,99 € |
| 9 | 1.358,68 € | 149,46 € | 1.209,22 € | 8.718,23 € | 1.281,77 € |
| 10 | 1.358,68 € | 76,91 € | 1.281,77 € | 10.000,00 € | 0,00 € |

interests is obtained by multiplying the 6% interest rate per the par_value;

capital_paid is the difference between the installment and the interest paid for a given year.

loan_paid is the sum of the parts of the capital each year that got paid.

to_be_paid is the difference between the capital to pay at given year minus the capital_paid  (the value of the first year in the first row is 10000-1358,68).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you tried?

I can propose something like this:

```
data test;
    attrib year par_value fixed_installment interest_rate interest capital_paid loan_paid to_be_paid format=best.;
    
    *-- Initial values --*;
    par_value = 10000;  
    fixed_installment = 1358.68;
    interest_rate = 0.06;
    loan_paid = 0;
    
    *-- Loop through 10 years --*;
    do year = 1 to 10;
        *-- Calculate interests --*;
        interest = round((par_value - loan_paid) * interest_rate, 0.01);
        
        *-- Calculate capital paid --*;
        capital_paid = fixed_installment - interest;
        
        *-- Calculate loan paid --*;
        loan_paid = loan_paid + capital_paid;
        
        *-- Calculate remaining loan --*;
        to_be_paid = par_value - loan_paid;
        
        output;
    end;
run;
```